# my app doesn't show in recently app list android

Tags: java, android

Good day . I have some problem with loading my app . When i load my app in my phone device , i can't see my app in recently apps in task manager and my label 
 of app is empty . Anybody had problem like i have ? I tried clean and rebuild project and after restart cashes   My manifest and style code  is below :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="rasulov.ason">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />

    <application
        android:name=".App"
        android:icon="@drawable/launcher"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.TransNav">
        <activity
            android:name=".Activities.MainActivity"
            android:label="">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Activities.ProfileActivty"
            android:label=""
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.TransNav" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Activities.CartActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_cart"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.TransNav" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Activities.SubCategoryActivity"
            android:label=""
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.TransNav" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Activities.ProductListActivity"
            android:label=""
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.TransNav" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Activities.DetailActivity"
            android:label=""
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.TransNav" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Activities.FilterProductActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_filter_product"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.TransNav" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Activities.PhotoVewPagerActivity"
            android:label=""
            android:resizeableActivity="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.TransNav" />
        <activity
            android:name=".FilterTools.RecyclerViewFragment"
            android:label=""
            android:resizeableActivity="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.TransNav" />
        <activity
            android:name=".FilterTools.RecyclerViewFragmentForColors"
            android:label=""
            android:resizeableActivity="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.TransNav" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Activities.RegistrationActivity"
            android:label=""
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.TransNav">

        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Activities.EditProfileActivity"
            android:label=""
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.TransNav">

        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Activities.SearchActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_search"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.TransNav">

        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>




<style name="AppTheme.TransNav" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.TransNav.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try giving a String value to the `label` in the `<activity>` tag.
It can sometimes happen if the `label` is set to "".

Comment: Thanks . I forgot about this rule of coding

Comment: Happens :) Please Accept the Answer if it helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

In your manifest file do these changes:

```
<manifest>
   <application
     android:label="Your application name">
        <activity
            android:label="Your activity name"/>
   </application>
</manifest
```